# How to resolve the Dokku 413 Request Entity Too Large error?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, dokku

I'm using Dokku to run a node API and recently hit the `413 Request Entity Too Large` error when trying to upload a file ~1.5mb.

I've followed the [Dokku Nginx docs](http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku/configuration/nginx/) and created a `nginx.conf.d` folder in the root of my project with `upload.conf` file that contains on entry - `client_max_body_size 20M;`

My understanding; this should modify your Nginx config next time you git push the app, but it is not working for me. What am I missing?

Comment: Check `nginx.conf.d` and `nginx.conf` permissions (must be to dokku:dokku), check if nginx.conf contain the line `include /home/dokku/myapp/nginx.conf.d/*.conf;` and/or finally try to manually restart nginx.

Answer (score 5):

It was my misunderstanding, you have to SSH to the server and execute the following as root:

```
mkdir /home/dokku/myapp/nginx.conf.d/
echo 'client_max_body_size 50M;' > /home/dokku/myapp/nginx.conf.d/upload.conf
chown dokku:dokku /home/dokku/myapp/nginx.conf.d/upload.conf
service nginx reload
```

Replace *myapp* with your app name

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Nginx-Max-Body-Size plugin](https://github.com/Zeilenwerk/dokku-nginx-max-upload-size). It also adds the `client_max_body_size` directive, and you can control it using a configuration variable:

`dokku config:set MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE=20M`

Answer (score 1):

Since Dokku 0.23.0 you can set it natively with:

```
dokku nginx:set node-js-app client-max-body-size 50m
```

Documentation:

https://dokku.com/docs/networking/proxies/nginx/#specifying-a-custom-client_max_body_size